# How to uninstall PHP 5.4.16

Tags: php, centos7, php-fpm

My VPS came with PHP 5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 installed and I am trying to install PHP 7+, but I have been unable to do so.

Then when I try to install a library, it conflicts, as shown here:

```
# yum -y install php-mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: repos-va.psychz.net
 * epel: mirror.us-midwest-1.nexcess.net
 * extras: mirrors.greenmountainaccess.net
 * ius: archive.linux.duke.edu
 * updates: mirror.vcu.edu
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 for package: php-mysql-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 for package: php-pdo-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php70w-common-7.0.27-1.w7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How can I completely remove this old version of PHP?

Comment: Get rid of the conflicting webtatic packages, and never go anywhere near their stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to install a newer version of PHP-MySQL module. You need to be aware that `mysql_` library was deprecated years ago and it has been removed entirely in PHP 7. Use a modern replacement such as `PDO` or `mysqli_` instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046)

If you are using CentOS 7, I recommend that you use IUS repository rather than webtatic. So you can disable or remove webtatic repo. I also recommend you remove packages installed from it. For example:

```
yum -y remove php70w*
```

Now install php7 after disabling or removing webtatic repo.

For php7.1*

```
yum -y install php71*
```

For php7.2*

```
yum -y install php72*
```

Try to see if MySQL is supported:

```
yum list installed | grep -i mysql
```

If you see `php71u-mysqlnd.*` for example, it is already supported.